# What is the set of functions such that any quotients of two of them at infinity is real or infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits

In this question [How to quantify asymptotic growth?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703005/how-to-quantify-asymptotic-growth) I was told that to assume $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is either real or $\pm\infty$, I have to assume a certain subset of non-oscillating functions for $f$ and $g$. I am wondering if simply eliminating trigonometric functions or any compositions of functions involving them from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is enough.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the big-Oh notation.  We do define a set of real functions by $O(f)$, but this set depends on a particular choice of function $f(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variety of functions is far more than you can imagine.  Functions with a limit as $x \to \infty$, even if you accept $\pm \infty$ as a limit, are *rare*.  You can't eliminate the ones that don't have a limit by something simple like banning trig functions.

As an example, take any function $f(x)$ that converges to a limit.  Now I define $g(x)=f(x)$ at all points except the integers.  At each integer, I make $g(x)=\pm 1$ randomly.  This is an uncountable family of functions that (except for a set of measure $0$) has no limit.

Comment: What if I restrict it to monotonic continuous functions?

Comment: Each monotonic continuous function has a limit as $x \to \infty$ because of the least upper bound principle. We can still ruin $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ having a limit.  Let $f(x)$ be positive decreasing and go to $0$ as $x \to \infty$.  Now define $g(x)=f(x)$ except where $f(x)$ drops through $10^{-k}$ for $k$ a natural, $g(x)$ drops by a factor of $10$ and stays there until $f(x)$ catches up.  On the other hand $h(x)$ sticks at $10^{-k}$ until $f(x)$ hits $10^{-(k+1)},$ then drops by a factor $10$.  The ratios will go crazy.  Band-aids like this never work.

Comment: I don't think the relation is transitive.  You should be able to find functions $f(x), g(x), h(x)$ such that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and $\frac {g(x)}{h(x)}$ both have limits but $\frac {f(x}{h(x)}$ does not.  I haven't thought about it enough to make an example.

Comment: What if I restrict to set of functions S such that f(x)/g(x) is monotonic for all x greater than some value N for some N for all functions f and g in S. Then, we need $(f(x)/g(x))'\not =0$ for all $x\geq N$, so $f'(x)/f(x)\not =g'(x)/g(x)$, meaning the solutions to $f'(x)/f(x)=g'(x)/g(x)$ must have an upper bound. In general, is there an easy way to find a set of real-to-real functions S such that there is an upper bound to the intersections between any two functions in S (max{x: f(x)=g(x), f,g in S}<infinity), without restricting S to something completely trivial like polynomials?

Comment: Regarding your f and g defined above, would that be continuous? Also, what about limiting functions to non-recursive ones?

Comment: As I defined $f$ and $g$ they are not continuous, but you can make them continuous by rounding off the jumps.  The point was just to make the ratios bounce around.   The ratios here will bounce between $10$ and $\frac 1{10}$ and not have a limit.

Comment: I see, thanks for the response, regarding my approach I found a mistake, so ignore the above.